# Label Printer with Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, printing, epson

I have an Epson TM-L60 Label printer and I'm trying to make it cut the paper after printing a report label made in Crystal Reports (from Visual Studio). I have to do it programatically because it's an old printer and driver settings do not allow me to set options like "single label cut".

Is there perhaps a command I can use?  But how do I send it from code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://support.epson.ru/products/manuals/200002/uni-mini-manual.pdf) you print a capital F in the font size 10 and with a font name of "control". I would have thought if you put an F where you want the cut to happen, in that font size and name it may work. You'll have to try!